# mysql gives error when trying to update

Tags: php, mysql

My query was:

```
$query = "UPDATE shop.titem  SET 
item = $nitem, comment = $comment visible = $visible
WHERE titem.item =$item;";
```

And the error I get is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'visible = 1 WHERE titem.item =lolipop' at line 2

I noticed that new version of `MySQL` doesn't really care about the hyphens so I chose to omit that. However, it gives me the same errors even though I use them for the variables.
Help please.

Comment: you seem to be missing a comma before visible

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) here and you have some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and provides a simple, reliable way of adding data to queries, plus it will handle issues with proper quotation of values. A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) outlines the recommended best practices when interfacing with databases.

Comment: I haven't been able to get around using mysqli and or tdo.  This is just a practice run but I hope to implement that in real jobs soon. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `comma`after $comment and `quotes` around string value:

try

```
$query = "UPDATE shop.titem  SET 
item = '$nitem', comment = '$comment', visible = '$visible'
WHERE titem.item ='$item'";
```

Comment: I feel so stupid. How the hell did i miss that. mybe because i feel sleepy. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after **$item;** inside the query and use '' for the string values

Answer (score 0):

Much better way to write the SQL query is :-

```
$query = "UPDATE shop.titem  SET item = '" . $nitem . "', comment = '" . $comment . "', visible = '" . $visible . "' WHERE titem.item = $item";
```

Also, I guess it should be **shop.item** instead of **shop.titem**.

Comment: No.  A "much better" way would be to execute a parameterised prepared statement.

Comment: That doesn't matter. It is a table item and the hyphens aren't needed like I said, it works fine in recent mysql